# Difference in Randomized Lasso and logistic regression in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

In python sklearn library, both RandomizedLogisticRegression and RandomizedLasso are supported as feature selection methods.

However, they are all using L1(Lasso) penalty, and I am not sure why both of them are implemented. In fact, I though that Lasso regression is the other term of L1-regularized logistic regression, but maybe there seems to be some difference.
I think even Linear SVM with L1 penalty(combined with resampling) will also produce the similar result.

Are there significant difference among them?

Comment: This may help: Limitation of L1-based sparse models is that faced with a group of very correlated features, they will select only one. To mitigate this problem, it is possible to use randomization, reestimating the model many times perturbing the design matrix or sub-sampling data and counting how many times a regressor is selected.RandomizedLasso implements this strategy for regression settings, using the Lasso, while RandomizedLogisticRegression uses the logistic regression, suitable for classification tasks. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#randomized-l1

Comment: Now I understood the difference of them. I thought L1-regularized logistic regression might hold the same characteristic of lasso regression. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#randomized-l1

> RandomizedLasso implements this strategy for regression settings, using the Lasso, while RandomizedLogisticRegression uses the logistic regression and is suitable for classification tasks. To get a full path of stability scores you can use lasso_stability_path.

RandomizedLasso is used for regression in which the outcome is continuous. RandomizedLogisticRegression on the other hand is for classification in which the outcome is a class label.

Comment: Ah, that was the difference, since randomized logistic regression still predicts the probability. Then RandomizedLogisticRegression would work as L1-regularized SVM. Thank you for your explanation David.